# For loop not stopping at finishing point

Tags: r, for-loop

I have some R code attempting to complete LU factorisation on a  square matrix A. However when I try to run the code I get an error saying;

```
Error in U[j, i] : subscript out of bounds
```

It seems like the for loop for the variable j isn't stopping, at first I thought it was because the i variable was looping up to nrow(A) - 1, then adding on 1 before ending the loop similarly to C. However, I printed out the i,j, and k variables and it seems to be that the j variable isn't stopping. Any idea's why?

```
LUD <- function(A) {

    if (!is.matrix(A)) {
        warning("argument is not a matrix: returning NA")
        return(NA)
    }
    L <- matrix(nrow = nrow(A), ncol = ncol(A))
    P <- matrix(nrow = nrow(A), ncol = ncol(A))
    for (i in 1:nrow(A)) {
        for (j in 1:nrow(A)) {
            if (i == j) {
                L[i, j] = 1
                P[i, j] = 1
            } else {
                L[i, j] = 0
                P[i, j] = 0
            }
        }
    }
    U = A

    for (i in 1:(nrow(A) - 1)) {

        max = which(U == max(U[i:nrow(A), i]), arr.ind = TRUE)
        k[i] = max[, 1]  ##finding position of largest element 

        temp = U
        U[i, ] = temp[k[i], ]  ## pivoting rows in U
        U[k[i], ] = temp[i, ]

        temp = L
        L[i, ] = temp[k[i], ]  ## pivoting rows in L
        L[k[i], ] = temp[i, ]

        temp = P
        P[i, ] = temp[k[i], ]  ##pivoting rows in P
        P[k[i], ] = temp[i, ]
        print(i)
        for (j in i + 1:nrow(A)) {
            print(j + 10)
            L[j, i] = U[j, i]/U[i, i]

            for (k in i:nrow(A)) 
            {
                U[j, k] = U[j, k] - L[j, i] * U[i, k]
                print(k + 100)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: This is my matrix:

```
A<-matrix(1:16,nrow=4,ncol=4)
```

Comment: Your `{` and `}` don't seem to match up. There isn't a `{` at the start of the function definition and there is a stray `}` right before the line `U=A`. Also, you seem to be trying to use `k` before giving it a meaning.

Comment: Ok, didn't know you had to have the whole function inside curly bracks. The { before the U=A actually does match up just forgot to indent it.  I thought it R you can declare your variables in the for loops?

Comment: You can declare variables anywhere you want but you cannot refer to an unexistent variable, like in `k[i]`. Outside the loop you can do `k <- NULL` in order to create it, then it will automatically grow as you index it `k[1], k[2]`, etc.

Comment: `k[i]=max[,1]` would only make sense if `k` is something like a vector. At that point `k` seems to be nothing at all. Later on you seem to use `k` as an integer index in a for-loop, but that is irrelevant.

Comment: @RuiBarrada I have made these changes, but it doesn't change the fact that j is counting past the dimension of the matrix. I might post the question again without the unnecessary details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you need to look into the the sequence you loop over. Try 
changing the second last loop from
    `for(j in i + 1:nrow(A))` 
to
    `for(j in (i + 1):nrow(A))`